# how to copy one folder to server

Tags: linux, terminal, ftp, ubuntu-9.04

i want to copy one folder to server using terminal...
iwant to copy datatable folder to server...
it like this:

```
copy from
user: /home/qa/html/datatable
to
server: www/html
```

how to do that...i'm new about this..i try like this:

```
1> qa@qadesktop2:~$ ftp 10230.35.211
2> fill password
3> ftp>cd www/html
4> ftp>mput
   (local-files)/home/qa/html/dataTable-1.6/*
```

Comment: Copy over which protocol ? FTP, SSH, NFS, ... ?

Comment: i'm using ftp..

Comment: Okay, so isn't that your answer?  Did that not work? What did that do and what did you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a graphical ftp client such as filezilla. This would be way easier for you if you have a graphical desktop.

[filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[LFTP](http://lftp.yar.ru/) and [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) can both be used to push files to a FTP server.

Comment: can you teach me step by step to copy this folder?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the manual?

Comment: ya..i've been try using ftp and also mput...but folder failed to copy...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial which gives you the command you have to use for upload,

[ftp tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/ftp-sftp-tutorial/)

Comment: i've been update my question...